# Rails find getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that includes a "belongs to" in the model.
The table includes the xx_id field to link the two tables.

But, sometimes the xx_id is going to be blank.
When it is, I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.
I don't want an error - I just want a blank display for this field.

What do you suggest?

Comment: How are you loading it to get this error?

Comment: I am thinking something like `if xx_id.nil? ""` syntax that would default the field to blank if the record is `nil` but not sure if that would cover the Not Found case.

Comment: If you're experiencing an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, while you can circumvent it with answers below, you likely have a completely separate issue within your application. Seems like the missing record shouldn't have been deleted, or some related record should have been deleted at the same time.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Rails will always raise an **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** exception when you use the `find` method. The `find_by_*` methods, however, return `nil` when no record is found.

The [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) tells us:

> RecordNotFound - No record responded to the find method. Either the
>   row with the given ID doesn't exist or the row didn't meet the
>   additional restrictions. Some find calls do not raise this exception
>   to signal nothing was found, please check its documentation for
>   further details.

If you'd like to return `nil` when records cannot be found, simply handle the exception as follows:

```
begin
  my_record = Record.find params[:id]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  my_record = nil
end
```

Comment: I think using `find_by_id` is a better solution for returning `nil` instead of catching an exception.

Comment: I agree :)

    `@model = Model.find_by_id(params[:model_id])
    if @model.nil? ...`

Comment: The dynamic `find_by` methods are vulnerable to SQL Injection, so try to use the find method as suggested in the answer. http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/03/rails-sql-injection-vulnerability-hold-your-horses-here-are-the-facts/

Comment: that's an old post and has been fixed. `find_by_id` is the right method to use.

Answer (score 12):

Can't you write

```
my_record = Record.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
```

Comment: This will also discard any errors not being `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. If you want to go with the rescue-solution rather than `.find_by_id` it would be better to only rescue from the specific expected error.

Comment: don't optimize prematurely

Comment: You could, but you should almost never use 'rescue nil' as it hides every possible error.

Answer (score 8):

```
Record.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

returns `Record` object if it is found or nil if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

When you call find, you'll obtain an array.
When array does not contain objects, count is zero.

```
items = Store.find(:all, :conditions => {:resource_id => item.id})
if item.count == 0 puts " !not found for item id#{item.id}"
```

or

```
if item.nil? puts " !not found for item id#{item.id}"
```

Comment: Note: this does not apply when calling find with an id