# Rails: check if ID doesn't exist in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Is it possible to do the following:

```
if @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    // logic here
else
    // do something if user doesn't exist
end
```

For some reason this throws the following error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: Can you show some more code? Model code for User? Actual output of the web server when you make that request?

Comment: This is as expected - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9709849/2864740

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is as expected](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

> [The] RecordNotFound [exception is raised if] No record responded to the `find` method. Either the row with the given ID doesn't exist or the row didn't meet the additional restrictions. Some find calls [like the `find_by*` methods] do not raise this exception to signal nothing was found ..

Use `find_by_id` (or `find_by`) which will return `nil` if the item is not found:

```
friendly.find_by_id params[:id]
friendly.find_by id: params[:id]
```

---

See also: [Rails find getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709659/rails-find-getting-activerecordrecordnotfound)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [Rails find getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709659/rails-find-getting-activerecordrecordnotfound), I would use begin/end because `.find` is *supposed* to raise an exception:

```
begin
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  # rest of code...
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  # other code; @user will automatically be nil since unassigned
end
```

But it's really a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Which is faster? `find` or `find_by_id`?

Comment: @Hopstream Speed is "the same". There is no inherent reason to choose one over the other based on "performance" - simply your preference and how you wish to structure the code :)

Comment: @Hopstream Technically, `find` is faster. I did a benchmark check on both 10 times. `find` took 0.001148 seconds on average, `find_by_id` took 0.001741 seconds on average.

Comment: @Charles If using begin/rescue in a controller, is the template supposed to get called after the rescue?

Comment: The begin/end statement doesn't affect view rendering. If when rescuing you don't want to render a view, simply `return false` inside the rescue block to stop the controller method - or, more elegantly, `redirect_to some_path and return false`